# Can't seem to get rid of the bullet points for the social media icons

Tags: html, css

I posted my link to GitHub, maybe someone can help me out with this.

I can't get rid of the bullet points from the social media icons for some reason.

Comment: Create a fiddle and show us the code here!

Comment: Please make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Don't make us go off site, work out which of the 8 html files we need to look at, before we even try to find the relevant html. Then there is the 160 lines of CSS most of which is probably irrelevant. By reducing the problem to directly replicate the issue, you may find this issue yourself, if not, it makes it a lot easier for us to find the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I figured it would be easier if I just post the link. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `list-style-type: none` to the ul tag containing those icons.